# show wrong record id from database laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

My Record :

```
ID : M110 (varchar)
Name : Book
Price : 3000
Stock : 10
```

My view :

```
@foreach($barang as $key => $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $value->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->price }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->stock }}</td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

My controller :

```
public function show($id)
{
    $barang = Barang::find($id);

    return view('barang.show', compact('barang'));
}
```

My Result :

```
ID : 0
Name : Book
Price : 3000
Stock : 10
```

how to show same id from database (varchar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following in your model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'id' => 'integer',
];
```

This will assure `id` is cast as `integer` even if it is stored as `varchar`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: Thanks it's work!
 
i change integer with varchar.

     protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'varchar',
    ];

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing that the ID is not returned as it was used for your query, hence you know it before the record is returned.
You can print out the ID from your query.

What does the Barang::find function actually do?

Comment: The `Barang::find()` function is highly likely to be the standard Laravel `find()` method for a `Barang` model

Comment: when i add id with number like 1,2,3,111,222 its show the right id.